# Popup required using qtip jquery

Tags: jquery, css, dhtml, qtip

I have the following code that needs to create a popup over the relevant box within the grid when a certain css class is attached to an element.  This css class is called PopupClass which can exist on any of the boxes.  I'm failing to get the popup working with the following code.  any help please?  many thanks!!!!

You can see that using jquery the code iterates over each 'PopupClass' and appends varying styles to the popup although i'm failing to see it successfully.

http://jsfiddle.net/Y4EYS/3/

Comment: you didn't include qtip.js in jsFiddle example, It seems working when I include it, http://jsfiddle.net/Y4EYS/4/

Comment: I don't get a popup weirdly..

Comment: you have set option "when" as click, so when I click, it's working, http://i.imgur.com/1TOI8.png

Comment: got it working now..  im just checking there's no issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try not using an .each loop to apply qtip because it automatically does that when calling...

`$('.PopupClass').qtip();`

It seems to work like this for me on your jsfiddle.

Comment: Yeah no problem, see here http://jsfiddle.net/rSNtc/1/ Note you have to click as that's how you set it but it definitely works.

Also the script wasn't included as mentioned previously, it actually works fine with .each but there really is no need for that bit of code regardless.